# Wordpress add_filter to element after hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook

Is it possible add a filter to a hook after an HTML element thats after the hook?

Example Template file:

```
do_action('hook_before_logo'); ?>

<a id="logo></a>

** location i want add content **
```

Or is it possible to add an element around the `<a id='logo'></a>` ? Like: `<div class="logo_container"><a id='logo'></a></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no". Hooks run at the place that the developer decided to place them. Any code before them, unless "someone somehow" stashed things in global scope,  is not available to the hook, and anything after will not have happened yet.

If you have access to the theme, however, you can just move the hook or create a new one.

You could also do this with JS:

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('#logo')
    .forEach(
        (thing) => {
            const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.classList.add('logo_container');
            thing.parentNode.appendChild(wrapper);
            wrapper.appendChild(thing);
        }
    );
```

*(Pedantic note, I'm using QSA with an ID in order to simplify the code.)*

Depending on your theme, you could also just do `display: none` on the logo and  write your own HTML in the `hook_before_logo` hook.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I want to make as few changes as possible to the template files so that if there is a parent theme update, as little as possible can break. `display: none` could be a work around but it will create a lot of extra code. I think i will create a new hook in the theme.